# Как грамотно прописать OnStop или onDestroy?

Tags: java, android, activity

Написал простое приложение, которое имеет 6 Активити.

Каждый раз, когда пользователь сворачивает и блокирует экран, а затем разблокирует его, приложение крашится.

Думаю, проблема в том, что нужно прописать `onStop` и `onDestroy`.

1. Я прав?
2. Если да, то нужно прописывать эти методы в каждом окне Активити?
3. Как грамотнее всего прописать (и какой метод лучше всего использовать), чтобы при блокировке экрана приложение просто останавливалось, а при повторном включении повторялся метод `onCreate`?

Comment: Являюсь новичком в этом деле, но я уверен, что ваша проблема не от того что вы не "прописали" эти методы (они реализованы по умолчанию для каждого активити, вы можете их перезаписать т.е переопределить) . Для выяснения причин почему крашится приложение нужно проанализировать логи в Logcat .

Comment: Методы ```onStop``` и ```onDestory``` вызываются системой для того, чтобы проинформировать вас от том что произошли эти события. Вам они могут быть необходимы для сохранения каких либо данных, закрытия каких-либо соединений и т.д. Поэтому: 1. вы не правы; 2: необходимости в обязательном переопределении данных методов нет; 3. метод ```onCreate``` вызывается 1 раз при создании активити, после разблокировки экрана вызывается метод ```onStart```. Для решения вашего вопроса прикрепите код вашей активити и стектрейс ошибки.

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю temq. Нужен код Activity и полный стектрейс ошибки.

Comment: @NickVolynkin , благодарю за подробное объяснение! Я уже сам разобрался с ошибкой. Приложение крашилось из-за того, что я неправильно определил Parse.initialization (parse.com). Не в том классе. Это и вызывало постоянное "падение" приложения.